# I got Yearling badge in 273 days

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, stack-overflow, yearling-badge

Today morning I got the `Yearling` badge - but [my profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/165297) clearly says that I have been a member for only 273 days.

Comment: +1 for the yearlying badge.

Comment: Are you sure you aren't from Venus?

Comment: @Daniel Google says it's 243 days in Venus. But yeah, I probably was in some other planet when I misread that page.

Comment: @Amarghosh Sometimes badges get a while to be awarded :)

Comment: @Daniel :) ....

Comment: I lol'd reading the title from the questions list: "I got Yearling badge in 273 days" `[status-bydesign]`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It probably says that you have *visited* the site on 273 days.

Your profile says:

> member for    1 year

When you hover over the "1 year," it says you joined on "2009-08-29 09:20:17Z," which is a year ago.

Comment: yeah what he said :)

Comment: Yup, that's it. Don't know what I was thinking.. I knew I'd be getting yearling badge by Aug-Sep 2010, but I never realized it is that time of the year... time flies so fast...!