# Description of the Yearling badge

Tags: bug, badges

Today, I got the Yearling badge.

I don't remember how my account was created, but I didn't use it for anything until February 2013 when I started being an **active** user. While I'm not happy with this achievement (because I think that that being logged in for searching answers, and suddenly decide to contribute and gain +200 in a few days should not qualify as "Yearling" beahavior), it seems that the rules for granting Yearling are by-design (see: [I got Yearling badge in 273 days](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/62758/i-got-yearling-badge-in-273-days),
[Yearling badge too early](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66041/yearling-badge-too-early),
[Details on how the Yearling badge works](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43240/details-on-how-the-yearling-badge-works)).

**In short**: I was not active for a year, yet I'm yearling, and that seems to be by-design.

Therefore, the description of Yearling is misleading:

> Active member for a year, earning at least 200 reputation

It should read:

> Member for a year, earning at least 200 reputation

Or

> Active member in a year, earning at least 200 reputation

Comment: You were active *in* the year.

Comment: It all depends on how you define "active". Active != visited necessarily

Comment: Well, i used to think that 200 reputation overall is enough for earning Yearling badges every year, but i never knew that i must gain 200 new rep every year to get that badge again.

Answer (score 2):

I believe the term "active" is being clarified with the second part of the "sentence".

It is stating that you are considered an active member if, within the last year, you have been a member of the site who earned at least 200 reputation. That's all.

Comment: As a programmer, I understand that sentence as `active && rep>=200` (the downvote is not mine)

Comment: As a programmer who deals with NLP on a daily basis, there are many subtleties and complexities to language, including interpretation.

Comment: Granted, but shouldn't a description be unambiguous?